# How to use XCode Cocoa Touch Framework classes from storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I've been tasked to research ways to protect intelectual property in a multi-vendor development scenario for an iOS app which makes heavy use of a single storyboard. I've played a bit with creating a XCode 6 Cocoa Touch iOS Framework to hide some of the details of our app, but I can't seem to expose ViewController subclases from the custom framework to the main application's storyboard (the application using that framework).

Is this possible? If so, are there any examples available?

Thanks in advance to any replies.

Best regards,
Adolfo

Comment: Duh. That's what I meant and that's what was going on, the framework was not linked yet.

Comment: Promoted my comment to an answer. If that fixed it, would you mind marking it as accepted? :-)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "expose ViewController subclass"? You mean Interface Builder isn't letting you set the class name of the controller? Have you linked your app against that framework?